# JQuery - Show text while typing

Tags: jquery

Im trying to show text, on a certain section, while typing on the other using jquery. I am using the following lines of code:

```
$('#sectionName').on('keyup', ()=> {
        $('#output-1').html($('#sectionName').val())
});
```

The code does work when I apply it to other dummy elements, however when I actually try to implement it on the website that I am working on it refuses to work.

To give a little bit more detail, a user presses a button to insert a section, the button will append a tab to the sidebar and then append a new section on the right hand side. From the right hand side a user is supposed to type the section name which is supposed to be reflected on the sidebar. However this does not happen. When I start typing the text is not being reflected.

The code I am using for inserting a new section:

```
function insertNewSection () {
// Inserting a new section

// Increment the session counter variable 
// to reflect how many sessions have been created
sessionStorage.setItem(
    'sectionCounter', Number(sessionStorage.getItem('sectionCounter')) + 1);
// Get the new sessionCounter value
const sectionCounter = sessionStorage.getItem('sectionCounter');

// Append the new section tab to the sidebar panel
$('#survey-format-panel > div').append(
    '<a id="output-'+ sectionCounter +'" class="custom-list-item form-control text-limit"></a>'
    );
// Append the new section on the right hand side / Content Side
var section = $('#section').html();
$('<div id="section-' + sectionCounter + '">' + section + '</div>').insertBefore('#section')

// Hide the already displayed cover page 
// and reaveal the new, blank section
$('#coverPage').hide();
```

}

Does anyone know what I am missing?

Comment: What is the difference between `#section` and `#sectionName`? What is `#input` (don't see it in your code)? Can you provide a fiddle that shows the issue?

Comment: #section refers to a hidden div in the html. #sectionName is used to id the input element that comes with the new section. #input is a typo it is actually supposed to be #sectionName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your elements are added dynamically, you must either define the event listener each time after adding a new element, or create one event handler using the principle of event delegation (so that it will work also for future elements not yet in the document).

And also, you need to determine the corresponding `output` element, which I suppose has the same sectionCounter in its `id` attribute:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '[id^="sectionName"]', function() {
     var sectionCounter = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1];
     $('#output-' + sectionCounter).text($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: You sir, just cured two days worth of a headache in just minutes. Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider attaching your event handler after adding the dynamic elements (a new section in your case) into the DOM as existing handlers won't work with the newly generated content or directives.